# How to get a solution in overdetermined matrix equation with zero-vector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have searching lots of pages but cannot fine clear answer.

I want to solve the matrix equation " $Ax = b$ " with in

- $A$ is a 10 x 6 matrix with all-known values
- $x$ is a vector(6x1) which I must found it
- $b$ is vector(6x1) which is zero vector [ (0,0,0,0,0,0)^t ]

[image]

values of $A$ is very dirty, such as 984367.670625554
and $x$ is not zero vector.

How can I get the $x$ vector?

I had studied about 'pseudo inverse' or 'SVD' but there is no clue about 'zero-vector'
and how to calculate 'eigenvalues' for a large and complicated matrix such I have.

I only can find the method of 'LSQ' and use 'pseudo inverse' with non-zero vector equation for 3x3 matrix.

I cannot use very famous library such as 'R' or 'Matlab', only I can choose 'C' or 'MS Excel'
I want to calculate the solution myself.

Please help me...